# did not update Laravel update function

Tags: php, laravel

working with Laravel 6 and going to update using controller
PostController

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(
               'title' => 'required|max:225',
               'body' => 'required'
        ));

        $post = Post::find($id);

        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->body = $request->input('body');

        $post->save();

        Session::flash('success','This post was successfully updated');

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
    }
```

and edit.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <form method="PUT" action="{{ action('PostController@update',$post->id) }}" > 
            {{csrf_field()}}
    

 <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" value="{{$post->title}}">

<label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Post Body</label>
    <textarea name="body" class="form-control" id="body"   rows="3">{{$post->body}}</textarea>
    </div>



            <div class="col-sm-6">
                
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" >Save Changers</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

but when click save changes button database did not updated!!! not generated any errors

Comment: Try form spoofing https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#form-method-spoofing . Also your html structure is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`method="PUT"` doesn't exist for `<form>` elements, valid values are `get`, `post` and `dialog`.

Change your

```
<form method="PUT" action="{{ action('PostController@update',$post->id) }}" > 
            {{csrf_field()}}
```

to

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('PostController@update',$post->id) }}" > 
  {{csrf_field()}}
  @method('put')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Model use to interact with table so all attributes which you need to store in DB you should need to define in your model as your Post model should look like

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body'];
}
```

or if you would like to make all attributes mass assignable, you may define the `$guarded` property as an empty array, like:

```
namespace App;
   
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Comment: this is not success here

Comment: Check with dumps if you are in correctly path to controller, thus `dd($post)` before you save, and check if model has be filled

Comment: same issue here

Comment: Follow from first step this tutorial: 
https://appdividend.com/2019/09/12/laravel-6-crud-example-laravel-6-tutorial-for-beginners/